# unable to open my SharePoint existing Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, library

When I tried to open my modern existing library in SharePoint communication site, i found the following error

"unable to get property code' of undefined or null reference in SharePoint library" ,But when i switched to classic mode, it can open .

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any recent changes to the library or page? New features enabled or new columns added? If there have not been any recent changes, it could also be a temporary issue due to a recent Microsoft update. (Check the Service Health page in your O365 tenant admin site.)

Comment: @Mike, Only the above features are enabled. No customize anything

Comment: As you have changed nothing, and it is SharePoint Online / Office 365, you should submit a support request through the Office 365 admin portal.

Answer (score 0):

Is this working fine before?

Recently Microsoft has done an update on some servers for some tenants. Maybe this is related to that update.

As Mike Smith suggested, you can submit a service request in the Microsoft365 admin center > Support > New service request. The engineers there know more about SharePoint Online, and they may know the cause of your issue.